# qTip doesn't show content when used in each loop

Tags: jquery, qtip2

I am trying to create tooltips from the contents of a DIV element using qTip + JQuery.
If I try to define tooltip with a static content, everything seems to be working fine. when I try to use them inside a for loop and get the contents of a DIV element and try to display it as tooltip, nothing shows up. I have the following code inside the document ready function.  The display property is set to none for the class 'tooltip'

```
$.each($(".tooltip"), function (i, val) {
             var theContent = $(val).html();
             $(val).qtip({
                 content: $(val).html,
                 style: {
                     width: 200,
                     background: '#ebf1ff',
                     color: 'black',
                     textAlign: 'center',
                     border: {
                         width: 1,
                         radius: 4,
                         color: '#AACCEE'
                     },
                     tip: 'bottomLeft',
                     name: 'dark'
                 }
             });
         });
```

My HTML tags looks like something below:

```
<div class="vBarContainer"><div id="gantt_65_1" class="gantt" style="border-width:medium;border-color:black;background:orange;width:6%;margin-left:0%;">0</div><div class="tooltip">Quantity:15453</div></div>
```

Can someone point to me as what I could be doing wrong?

Thanks,
javid

Comment: Maybe a jsFiddle demonstration?  The qTip developer provides [a link to a blank jsFiddle with qTip included](http://jsfiddle.net/craga89/fDavN/).

Comment: I managed to get it working by using the sibling property of the div enclosing the gantt class.

Comment: @user320587 do not edit your question with your solution, please put your solution as answer and check your own answer as solution.

Answer (score 1):

My Solution: Managed to get it working by using the sibling property of the div next to the tooltip div element

```
$('.gantt').each(function () {
         $(this).qtip({
             content: $(this).siblings('div.tooltip').html(),
             style: {
                 width: 200,
                 background: '#ebf1ff',
                 color: 'black',
                 textAlign: 'left',
                 border: {
                     width: 1,
                     radius: 4,
                     color: '#AACCEE'
                 },
                 tip: 'bottomLeft',
                 name: 'dark'
             },
             position: {
                 corner: {
                     target: 'topMiddle',
                     tooltip: 'bottomLeft'
                 }
             }
         });
     });
```

Comment: I had a similar problem and this solution worked :) Many thanks!